# Determining Packet Loss on TCP connection on Win32 programmatically

Tags: winapi, networking, tcp, winsock

I have a win32 application that uses winsock to create TCPIP sockets.

This is great, except in some cases I would like to know statistics on the actual socket.  Stuff like packets sent, received, total bytes sent, etc.  But the most important piece of data I want to see is packet loss.

I have not been able to find the right call to get such data, I have looked at getsockopt and cannot find a good way to get such data.

Is there a way to get low level statistics of a TCP socket on the windows API?

For reference I am using Windows 7 (64-bit version)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GetTcpStatisticsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366023(v=vs.85).aspx). It returns the [MIB_TCPSTATS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366915(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, which contains among other things the retransmission count:

```
typedef struct _MIB_TCPSTATS {
  DWORD dwRtoAlgorithm;
  DWORD dwRtoMin;
  DWORD dwRtoMax;
  DWORD dwMaxConn;
  DWORD dwActiveOpens;
  DWORD dwPassiveOpens;
  DWORD dwAttemptFails;
  DWORD dwEstabResets;
  DWORD dwCurrEstab;
  DWORD dwInSegs;
  DWORD dwOutSegs;
  DWORD dwRetransSegs;    // <=========
  DWORD dwInErrs;
  DWORD dwOutRsts;
  DWORD dwNumConns;
} MIB_TCPSTATS;
```

> **dwRetransSegs**
>     Type: **DWORD**
>
> The number of segments retransmitted.