# How to know packet loss stats of specific TCP socket in Windows? Similar to how Resource Monitor is showing?

Tags: c++, tcpsocket, windows-api-code-pack

I want to know how to find Packet Loss % and Latency stats from TcpConnectionEstatsPath

Comment: Try [GetTcpStatisticsEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993997/determining-packet-loss-on-tcp-connection-on-win32-programmatically).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I want to know Packet loss information per TCP Receiver Socket.